# Django Admin Login Cookie browser configuration message

Tags: django-admin, session-cookies

We have a peculiar problem with logging in to django admin on our dev server - just surfaced today, sept 1st. When we try to log in using staff usernames and passwords we are returned the following message:

> Looks like your browser isn't configured to accept cookies. Please enable cookies, reload this page, and try again.

We encounter the same problem on our local installations:

- I was using django 1.1.1 upgraded to 1.1.2 problem with both returning same
- Another developer encountered the same problem on a fresh 1.2.1 installation

I read a lot of chatter about setting `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` & `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE`, we never had these set on any of our installations and never encountered any problems. We then specified the following in our local installations to no avail.

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '127.0.0.1:8000'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
```

This problem just appeared today, yesterday things were fine on local installations, cookies are enabled on all our browsers.

Any one experiencing the same? any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

It turns out it was a simple cookie problem using chromium-browser---my profile was corrupt--- which started an escapade of changing settings.py and other things, which broke other browsers etc.

Ah well, solved now.

Comment: please mark your answer as correct and fill in some details. Stackoverflow is powered by users giving actual information, if you can answer your own question it's nice to share